# Delete row from database after 24 hours in php

Tags: php

I want to create something like Snapchat that will automatically delete row after 24 hours in php/mysql. I have read about cron jobs,but it slows down apps,so i was wondering if there is other way to do it?

Comment: You can use SQL in-built function triggers to achieve this. You can create a trigger which will execute in every 1 hours and will check all records of the table. If record created datetime is greater than 24 hours, it will delete the record as below:

    CREATE EVENT hourly_record_cleanup
      ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
      DO
        DELETE FROM messages
          WHERE createdtime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOURS);

Hope it helps you.

Comment: why re-asking same question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
DELETE FROM snaps WHERE created_at<=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the expiry date as a column in the table, and only query rows that haven't expired yet.